# Code formatting instructions are incomplete

Tags: bug, code-formatting, documentation

The code block instructions say

> To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces:

but it fails to mention that you also need to have a blank line before the code block as well.

For instance, this example won't work because there is just a new line after this text and four spaces
    Some code example

and this example will work because there is a blank line

```
Some code example
```

Is this a bug or documentation error?

Comment: That's not a bug, but indeed the documentation could be clearer. (This doesn't apply just to code blocks, lists also need a blank line.)