# False code detection from the outside code-block when inserting the reference

Tags: bug, markdown, code-block

Inserting the reference after the code block causes an error.
I have to use a line break to solve it, but want it to be possible not to use hacks, because after the code block I write not code but text, and expect that in first screenshot should be no errors.
Screenshot №1:

> [image: Error]

Screenshot №2:

> [image: "Hack" 1]

Screenshot №3:

> [image: "Hack" 2]

[Link to my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73966440/14928633)  in which I encountered the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code formatting instructions are incomplete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167432/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/282094

Comment: This was already [identified by rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274337/323179).

Comment: @Rob Now I see that problem has already been [described](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357785/917790), it would be great at least fix the code filter error message.

Comment: Kirogasa, fixing the message on a few years old complaint appears to have been missed, but the FAQ might be updated to warn not to use *extended* markdown (nothing fancy) and to stick with the standard `[1]: http://link.com/` (or inline) links as created by the editor. --- If you agree it's a duplicate you can close this with one vote to close.